# Map AuthenticationToken for WIndows Phone 8.1

Tags: dictionary, windows-phone-8.1, msdn

I found many similar questions here but I still don't understand how to get an **AuthenticationToken** for my `MapControl` in windows phone 8.1 application.
Okay, maybe I'm really stupid but in Official MSDN guide they said:

1. In your browser, navigate to your developer **dashboard** in the Windows
   Phone Dev Center.
2. On the Dashboard page, click **Submit App**.
3. On the Submit app page, click **App info**.
4. On the **App info** page, reserve an app name and provide the other info
   requested on the page. Then click Save.
5. On the **Submit app** page, click **Map services**.

And I don't see any **Submit App** menu item in my dashboard.

[image]

I suggest that **Submit an app** and **Submit App** mune items is similar so I click it. According to the MSDN guide I should see **Map Services** link , but I don't.

[image]

Can anyone tell me is the guide is up to date? How can I get what I want? I know that this is a really simple thing. Thank you!

P.S. Sorry for my English;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you went to Windows 8 dashboard, not Windows Phone dashboard.
The Windows Phone dashboard is here: https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/dashboard

Here are the steps:

1. Select Windows Phone dashboard http://prntscr.com/7p29s1
2. Click on submit app http://prntscr.com/7p2a1h
3. Fill app info and get the token http://prntscr.com/7p2aby

If you have any more questions please let me know!